# how can i display data in Tkinter treeview fetched from Mysql table using python

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, treeview

am have created a table using treeview and i would like to insert in data fetched from mysql table.if any one can help me because i have tried all my level best but still in vain.with this statement `tree.insert("", 1, text=2, values=("name", "5", "5"))` can insert well data but not from the database, but i would like to fetch from the database and display it.
here is the code i have tried but it has failed.please help.
`

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import MySQLdb

root = Tk()
root.geometry("320x240")

tree = ttk.Treeview(root)

conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "drake", "OSCAR")
cursor = conn.cursor()

tree["columns"] = ("one", "two", "three")
tree.column("one", width=100)
tree.column("two", width=100)
tree.column("three", width=100)

tree.heading("#0", text='ID', anchor='w')
tree.column("#0", anchor="w")
tree.heading("one", text="NAME")
tree.heading("two", text="VOTES")
tree.heading("three", text="PERSENTAGE")

for i in range(1, 6):
    cursor.execute("""select name from president where ID =%s""", (i,))
    nm = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    cursor.execute("""select votes from president where ID =%s""", (i,))
    vot = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    cursor.execute("""select percentage from president where ID =%s""",(i,))
    percent = cursor.fetchone()[0]

    tree.insert("", i, text=i, values=(nm, vot, percent)),

tree.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve your problem, first you will need to read all the rows of the database using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM president
```

which you need to execute:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM president""")
```

Now, simply loop over the rows and insert them one by one in `tree`:

**UPDATE:**

I suppose your table structure is like this:

```
ID | name | votes | percentage
```

So you could run this:

```
cpt = 0 # Counter representing the ID of your code.
for row in cursor:
   # I suppose the first column of your table is ID
   tree.insert('', 'end', text=str(cpt), values=(row[1], row[2], row[3]))
   cpt += 1 # increment the ID
```

Comment: hello@Bill,am receiving an Typeerror: 'cursor' object is not callable.its from the `for (name,votes,percentage) in cursor:`

Comment: Check my edit. Tell me if the structure of your table is as I mentioned @ByamukamaOscar

Comment: yes,its like that and am going to try out and see .thanks for effort you have put @bill

Comment: If you have further troubles with this code, do not hesitate to ask

Comment: Why `ttk.Scrollbar` not working when fetching data from database. It is working while inserting data directly to `tree`

Answer (score 1):

iv used sqlite3 not MySQL but i am assuming that the value that is returned from the sql is put into a multidimensional array, these are array which require more than one index e.g

```
array[0][1]
```

the code below is for modifying the tree

```
for i in self.tree.get_children():
    self.tree.delete(i) #clears current values from tree

for student in StudentList:
    self.tree.insert("" , 0,values=(student[0],student[1])
    #the index used would depend on what you want to be put into the tree
    #only uses one index per value instead of two as the for loop changes the first index
```

note that this was copied from my coursework(booking system) hence the names used